# Where is @anim/fragment_fade_enter included in?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

`@anim/fragment_fade_enter` was included in `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.4` but after I updated it to version `1.3.3` I can't seem to be able to resolve it anymore, all I can find online that it's supposed to be included in Androidx Core https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/animator/fragment_fade_enter.xml
but using `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2` doesn't help either.

Did it get refactored into another dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@anim/fragment_` resources were always a private implementation detail of the various `FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_` fields (i.e., [`TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)) used in the [`FragmentTransaction.setTransition()` API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#setTransition(int)).

As per the [Fragment 1.3.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0):

> - **TRANSIT_ animation changes**: The fragment default effects, `TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN`, `TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE`, and `TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE`, now use `Animator` instead of `Animation`. The resources used to build these animators are now private.

So if you are using Fragments by themselves, you should use the `setTransition()` API, rather than manually using any of those private animators.

If you are using the Navigation Component, the `navigation-ui` dependency **does** offer public animators as of the [Navigation 2.3.1 release](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.3.1). You'd use those with:

- `@animator/nav_default_enter_anim`
- `@animator/nav_default_exit_anim`
- `@animator/nav_default_pop_enter_anim`
- `@animator/nav_default_pop_exit_anim`

As of this time, those are also fade animations.

Comment: I'm using Navigation Component yes, this makes sense now but I couldn't figure that out from the changelog, thank you for explaining it.